# Resizeable Number Triangle in Java GUI

Tags: java, loops, user-interface

I have this assignment for a Java class I am taking. I was assigned to do this:

Write a program that displays numbers as shown below. The number of lines in the display changes to fit the window as the window resizes.

This is whats displayed in the GUI ( without the large spaces in between lines):

1

12

123

1234

12345

123456

1234567

with the numbers counting larger and the number of lines increasing as I expand the GUI window.

Heres my code that I have now:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class ResizingGUI extends JPanel{
    public int width = 600;
    public int height = 200;
    public int x_coord = 10;
    public int y_coord = 40;
    public static final int point_size = 12;
    public Font fontObject = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, point_size);
    public int maxLines = 16;

    public ResizingGUI (){
        super();
        setSize(width, height);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.setFont(fontObject);
        x_coord = 10;
        y_coord = 40;
        int lineCount = 0;
        int line = 1;
        maxLines = (this.getHeight()-40)/10;
        while(lineCount < maxLines){
            while(line < maxLines){
                String s = String.valueOf(line);
                g.drawString(s, x_coord, y_coord);
                line++;
                x_coord = x_coord + 10;
                if(line > 10){
                    x_coord = x_coord + 5;
                }
            line = 0;
            lineCount++;
            y_coord = y_coord + 10;
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Resizeable GUI");
        frame.setSize (600,200);
        frame.getContentPane().add (new ResizingGUI());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I think this might be the solution, but the nested loops are throwing me for a loop (hah)
If anyone could please advise on either a way to fix the nested loops or (more likely) how to achieve my goal, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Use `paintComponent` instead of `paint`, override `getPreferredSize` instead of using `setSize`, use compound `for-loop`s instead of `while-loop`s and use `FontMetrics`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loops are a little confusing, basically, you want to loop for the number of lines and the loop for the number columns (which is the current line number)...

```
int line = 0;
while (line < maxLines) {
    int col = 0;
    while (col < line) {
        //...
        col++;
    }
    line++;
}
```

You're also no resetting the `x_coord` back to it's initial position, meaning that each new line will start at the end of the last line...just below it.

You should also:

- Override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`.  Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details
- Override `getPreferredSize` instead of using `setSize`. It will work better with the layout managers
- Make use of the `FontMetrics` in order to determine how many pixels you need to adjust for each line/column. Take a look at [Measuring Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your help! The FontMetrics was a great idea, and the way you counted your loop inspired my final solution.